# Why $F \rightarrow T \implies \neg F \rightarrow \neg T \implies T \rightarrow F$ is wrong?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$$
F \rightarrow T \implies \neg F \rightarrow \neg T \implies T \rightarrow F
$$
Why is this reasoning wrong according to the truth table of implication in logic?

Thanks.

Comment: Focus on $F \to T \implies\lnot F \to\lnot T$, as $\lnot F \to\lnot T \implies T \to F$ is correct.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are $T$ and $F$ truth values? Or are they statements? Also, what is the distinction you're making between "$\rightarrow$" and "$\Rightarrow$"?

Comment: What is $\implies$ -- does that mean "simplify to"?

Comment: I'd argue that F -> T implies not T -> not F

Comment: It's a tautology if $T$ and $F$ are logical propositions (unusual) and $\implies$ is equivalent to $\to$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through your statements one at a time:
$$
F \to T
$$
Looking at the truth table, this evaluates to $T$ (true).
$$
\lnot F \to \lnot T
$$
(I use $\lnot$ to denote "not") -- this one simplifies to $T \to F$. Then looking at the truth table, it's $F$.
$$
T \to F
$$
As we just saw, that is also $F$ (false).

---

So it looks like your problem is going from $F \to T$ to $\lnot F \to \lnot T$. That jump is not correct. In general,
$$
A \to B \text{ is equivalent to } \lnot B \to \lnot A
$$
but
$$
A \to B \text{ is not necessarily equivalent to } \lnot A \to \lnot B.
$$

Comment: A→B is equivalent to ¬B→¬A this is what a was missing then. Thanks

Comment: @FriendlyFullStack You are welcome

Comment: Could you please give me a reference containing the proof of this rule "A→B is equivalent to ¬B→¬A" ?

Comment: For the curious ones: proof of  rule "A→B is equivalent to ¬B→¬A" https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3070256/633862

Answer (score 1):

This is because, unlike algebra with equality operations $=$, you do not preserve truth in logical implications $\rightarrow$ by performing the same operation on both sides.

I assume you started with 
$$
F \rightarrow T
$$
which is correct, and then proceeded to negate both sides like this 
$$
\neg F \rightarrow \neg T
$$
However this is *not true* because of how $\rightarrow$ works with the implication.

Comment: " unlike algebra, you do not preserve truth in logic by performing the same operation on both sides" I think that's misleading. The point isn't that logic is different from algebra, it's that "$\rightarrow$" is different from "$=$." E.g. you can't do the same thing to both sides of an inequality in algebra, either: $2<3\not\rightarrow -2<-3$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Beat me to it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber tried to make it more clear what I was saying